# 'be had' - please explain the meaning and grammar, if any relevant, for this use

Tags: word-usage

I found this example.

"The lawyer should carry out an analysis and advise on the legal alternatives if the case does not settle, including the prospects at trial and the costs. This discussion could ***be had*** with the client both before and during the mediation."

Although the meaning '***be had***' can be discerned from the context in which it appears, I have no idea:

- what is the general meaning of it devoid of this context?
- what sort of rules, if any, does apply here that made use of it in this situation?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1):

We're dealing with the verb "[to have](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have)."  Although any definition of "to have" can be used with the phrase "could be had," it is most common to use "to have" in the context of to possess, obtain, or acquire.  Thus, "could be had" means, "could be obtained/acquired/possessed by."  The phrase is used to identify a condition by which some object or result can be acquired, if desired.

There is something important you need to realize about your example (and it's odd, since we're talking about lawyers and the use of language is their stock-in-trade).  You can interpret the use of "could be had" in two different ways.

- As a colloquialism for "could be held."  One can both have and hold a discussion, and the phrase "could be had" is, in my locale, uncommon enough that this would be a common mistake.  There are minor differences between having and holding discussions or meetings.  (Paul Carpenter, Writer at 3D Systems, briefly discusses the differences between "have a discussion" and "hold a discussion" over at [Quora.com](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-correct-the-secretary-wanted-to-have-a-discussion-on-or-about-the-matter-with-the-teachers).)
- As an implied consequence of the discussion, which is what "could be had" better references.  In this case, it's the *alternatives* discussed in the previous sentence that "could be had" *as a result of the discussion.*  The sentence is implying the alternatives since they had already been mentioned.

Lawyers usually want things to be interpreted in only one way.  Nevertheless, these subtleties are technical and don't substantially change the meaning of the sentence.